# Conditionally format cells in a column based on whether either of two cells is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I want to format the font color in cells of column G if both cells in column E and F of the same row are blank.

```
     E       F            G
-----------------------------------------    
1 (blank) (blank) (font color white)
2 xxxxxxx xxxxxxx (font color black)
3 (blank) xxxxxxx (font color black)
4 (blank) (blank) (font color white)
5 (blank) xxxxxxx (font color black)
```

`xxxxxxx` denotes that the cell is not blank.

Comment: Did you try using `COUNTBLANK` in your CF formula. What did you try?

Comment: Typically, setting the font color to white is done to hide the cell's results from view. If this is your intention, you may want to abandon the white font color as the CF rule's format and use a *custom number format* of `;;;` which effectively blanks the cell's value unless the cell is showing an error. If you want to avoid showing an error look into the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/IFERROR-function-f59bacdc-78bd-4924-91df-a869d0b08cd5).

Answer (score 2):

`=AND(ISBLANK($E1),ISBLANK($F1))`

should do it.

Comment: `ISBLANK` does not count a cell with an empty string (e.g. "") returned from a formula as blank but `COUNTBLANK` does. If columns E & F contain formulas that may return an empty string then this might be better as `=COUNTBLANK($E1:$F1)=2`.

Comment: No argument there. It never fails to amaze me how SO attracts so many super-secret projects that cannot have their specifics discussed even in a redacted manner.